# Is there anyway to use startWith in LeftJoin Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have the following code:

```
  $get_order = DB::table('orders')
                 ->leftJoin('postcodes', 'orders.postcode', '=', 'postcodes.postcode')
                 ->where('order_ref', '=', $order_ref)
                 ->first();
```

What I am trying to achieve, is do a left join if `postcodes.postcode` starts with `orders.postcode` . Is there any way to make this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain me in detail?

Comment: see if this works `->leftJoin('postcodes', 'postcodes.postcode','LIKE', DB::raw( "CONCAT(orders.postcode, '%')" ))`

Comment: @PawelBieszczad Your solution worked like a charm, please create an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $get_order = DB::table('orders')
             ->leftJoin('postcodes', 'postcodes.postcode','LIKE', DB::raw( "CONCAT(orders.postcode, '%')" )) 
             ->where('order_ref', '=', $order_ref)
             ->first();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
->leftJoin('postcodes', function($join) {
        $join->on('postcodes.postcode', '=', 'orders.postcode')
             ->on('postcodes.postcode', 'LIKE', "startWith%"));
})
```